# Showing error in the "flutter doctor" about Android toolchain

Tags: android, macos, flutter, terminal, android-sdk-2.3

Showing error about android toolchain

```
!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
✗ Android license status unknown.
  Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for
  detailed instructions.
```

So I read about this on how to fix this

So I found a command named "flutter doctor --android-licenses"
and output of "flutter doctor --android-licenses" is

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found
(/Users/sagarkhurana/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try  re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

and I already have android studio and and it's SDK location is "/Users/sagarkhurana/Library/Android/sdk"

Please help me I searched it alot but got no result
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by following the solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462340/android-sdk-is-missing-a-tools-folder-meaing-no-sdkmanager-meaning-android-li); I use Linux but I believe it will fix your problem regarding the operating system you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Open Android studio > go to SDK manager from more actions > in android SDK option select SDK tools > install android SDK command-line tools(latest) and accept the licence.

It will run and if it still shows some licence is missing type the command given in the cmd and run flutter doctor again after accepting the licence.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the `JDK` software installed or if **JAVA_HOME** is not set, then `Flutter` will give this error message. The following tasks provide the information you need to install the `JDK` software and set **JAVA_HOME** on **UNIX** or **Windows** systems.

Download software from the below-given link.
[Download here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html)

After a successful installation, you can now check from the command line using the below command.

- C:\Users\Ainswers>java -version
- java version "1.8.0_251"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)

Kindly exit flutter console (if it is open) then open it again for fresh **restart** then try to run flutter doctor again. Hope you will get a green check right now.

Answer (score 0):

just download java for it and
it will work well.
it happened to me too just try it,
download and install java on your system

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29780658)

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK Tools in Android studio SDK manager, and check on **Android SDK Command-line Tools (Latest)** then install it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK manager and click on edit in front of your SDK path then install both versions of the SDK.

And Restart your computer

This will definitely fix the problem.