# I am trying to run flutter but facing the issue as shown in the below attached snapshot

Tags: flutter, android-studio, command-prompt

I was trying to install flutter following the steps mentioned in the FLutter documentation. `flutter doctor` showed me 2 errors as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xCZu.png)
Can anyone please solve my query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing error in the "flutter doctor" about Android toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473230/showing-error-in-the-flutter-doctor-about-android-toolchain)

Answer (score 0):

If you have android studio installed then go to its sdk manager settings, select the tab sdk tools, look for android sdk command line tools and install the latest one. The other error is about you haven't accepted the android-licenses just copy and paste the command `flutter-doctor --android-licenses` in the command prompt, it will give some licenses probably 4 or 5 over which you have to press y to accept them and both of your errors will be gone.