# i am getting an error in Android toolchain when i ran flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have started with the setup of flutter updated version and am a total beginner in this platform. This is the error I have been getting. Could you please help me?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android/Sdk is missing a Tools folder, meaing no sdkmanager, meaning "Android license status unknown" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462340/android-sdk-is-missing-a-tools-folder-meaing-no-sdkmanager-meaning-android-li)

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Android SDK Command-line Tools (in SDK Manager).

[image]

After Installing, accept the android licensces (in CMD)

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

Either install Android Studio to get the required dependecies or download an android sdkmanager and check its path (`path/to/sdkmanager` should be the path to that).

To avoid any problems for beginners, I would just install Android Studio [here](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=ds), set it up until it installs the android sdk, then switch to Flutter: that was the only way to fix this since some time ago if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

Please first run this command

flutter doctor --android-licenses

then follow this link :  [Android/Sdk is missing a Tools folder, meaing no sdkmanager, meaning "Android license status unknown" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462340/android-sdk-is-missing-a-tools-folder-meaing-no-sdkmanager-meaning-android-li)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a directory (android-sdk) to install android-sdk
- Download [Command Line Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-line-tools-only)
- Create a directory and Uncompres Command Line Tools to `android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest` folder
- Add `android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` to `PATH`
- run:

```
yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools" "build-tools;33.0.1" "platforms;android-30" "sources;android-30"
```

- add to path: `android-sdk/platform-tools`

> maybe you need run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Ready!! can run `flutter doctor` again

> for windows and mac it's the same