# I am trying to install flutter and work in VS Code editor

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

iam I am trying to install flutter and work in vs codeVS Code editor

So firstFirst I downloaddownloaded the latest version of flutter ..ans install vs codeand installed VS Code, then I addadded the extensionextensions flutter and dart ..then Then I connect my device in usb and put it in developer mode .. And then I wrote in terminal 'flutter doctor " to validation if I make true .. so the device is appear in the bottom of screen of vsc but when I press f5 or wrote in terminal ' flutter run ' don't run .. and the problem is in image and I don't know how to solve it .. sorry

Sorry for my English language itsit's not perfect .. [I try a lot of things and failed] sorry I try a lot of things and failed

Sorry for a lot of talking thanks

Thanks.

Comment: The image is missing from the question. Also please paste the error here

Comment: Does   [cmdline-tools component is missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68236007/10157127) answer your question. Also follow the [installation guide.](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install)

Comment: Kaushik Chandru sorry for image .. iam beggainer in stackoverflow and dont know why dont let me to send the screen for ` flutter doctor ` command .. i will try to past it here

Comment: Yeasin Sheikh yes is missing and iam trying to download it right now .. thanks

Comment: Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

Comment: [X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install vs2019 to use desktop version and chrome, its obviously clear

Follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes) and install vs2019 ,then install desktop development with c++

For cmdline-tool error follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter)
You need to install sdk then run `flutter doctor --android-lienses` to accept sdks

I think its better to see answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462340/android-sdk-is-missing-a-tools-folder-meaing-no-sdkmanager-meaning-android-li), just research on internet to solve this.

- [this is example in youtube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DIhebxWdoxws&ved=2ahUKEwjetImGt7X5AhX7gv0HHQzUBnIQjjh6BAgnEAI&usg=AOvVaw2ky0LPzQOVfZMRh2wEF8jw)

Comment: SORRY I POST THE IMAGE TO DECLARE THE PROBLEM .. BUT DOESNT SEND ..

Comment: I WILL SHARE IT AGAIN

Comment: THE IMAGE IS PHOTO ABOUT RESULT WHEN I WROTE IN TERMINAL ' FLUTTER DOCTOR; AND YOU WILL SEE THAT I INSTALLED THE ANDROID STUDIO

Comment: must i have to installed the  the vs if i don't want to make desktop apps???

Comment: i don't need the chrome ,so must i have to install it ??

Comment: I dont think so, but you have to install toolchain and license

Comment: First solve toochain and cmdline-tool then if you couldnt run, install vs2019

Comment: ok ... i work for that know ...